# M1 BigSur keybind to swap "Option + ArrowKey" to "Control + ArrowKey"?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, big-sur, apple-silicon

Is there anyway to change "option + arrow keys" to "control + arrow keys"? Essentially I want to be able to bind it just like windows. Move from word to word, delete by the word etc

I was able to swap around the control/option/command key within the Keyboard settings but that's not necessarily what I'm looking for. I'm trying to get the actual functionality of "moving from word to word" by using the control + arrowKey.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've tried that earlier but that didn't work out for me unfortunately. Maybe I'm doing it incorrectly? I navigated to my Library folder, made a folder named "KeyBindings", and created a textEdit file named "DefaultKeyBinding" with the copied and pasted content from that link. I also tried naming the file "DefaultKeyBinding.dict" as well.

Comment: The file does need the extension, and must be in the exact path provided in the linked answer (i.e. `~/Library` not `/Library`). Make sure you've relaunched any apps for the change to take effect in the app. Which apps are you trying it in? KeyBindings only works for apps using the macOS text editing APIs for its text editor (i.e. not Microsoft Word). Please [edit] with how you get on since comments are ephemeral and will be removed at some point.